# Some property is missing in json response of api

Tags: asp.net, json

I am calling api from my system.I am storing response of that into database.I am getting response in json format.I deserilized it.I have created class for that.
Ex:

```
public class Result
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string SurName{ get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

In some response I am getting SurName and in response  not getting SurName property.I am using same sp for insertion.That's why I am getting error when SurName property not present.How to handle that?

Comment: How do you want to handle that? Surely that's a decision for the business to decide what to do in the event of missing data? Do you reject the whole thing if there is data missing? Or do you make do and insert what you have and put in a default value instead of the missing data?

Comment: If that property absent ,want to put null/empty into table.

Comment: So, what is your current insertion code, and what is the error message you are getting with it?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Colin.Better to accept null as parameter value in sp rather than checking property present in response,

Comment: Without the code, I can't see what you're currently doing.... But at a wild guess maybe something like this: `blah.Surname ?? DbNull.Value` when you add the parameter to the DbCommand (You haven't even said what the back end database is). You really need to provide a lot more context with your questions, it will make it much easier for people to answer you.